# Skrollr: Scroll down, pause, scroll to bottom

Tags: animation, scroll, skrollr

I'm sorry, but I can't get this working:
Scroll down the page to a certain position. Then pause scrolling and animate something. After that **scroll down to the bottom of the page**.

How do I make Skrollr scroll the end of the page without feeding absolute values to it?

I know the pausing demo, but that works with sections that always fill the whole window. But my section that follows the animated part is *larger* than that so I can't just say: change its position from -100% to 0% or something like that.

Comment: The way you've phrased it, it sounds like this should happen automatically, without the user interacting? If you want to scroll to the end of the page, just do `setScrollTop(getMaxScrollTop())`

Comment: No, it should not happen automatically, manually. I'll try what You suggested.